# ASIHTTPRequest crashes the app on ios8

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, ios8, asihttprequest

Here I am using JSON to parse the data with `ASIHTTPRequest`
The same code is working fine for my lower version of iOS. (iOs7 & below)
But I am not able to run this on my iOS-8 device.

The log is getting well, but the app crashes,
may be getting late reply from server.
It should not crash for late reply.

Does any new modification required for iOS-8 for `ASIHTTPRequest`?

Same code for lower version working well.

If I tried to check with debugger ON with  each method, I found my code is crashing right here:

```
-(void)startSynchronous
{
#if DEBUG_REQUEST_STATUS || DEBUG_THROTTLING
    ASI_DEBUG_LOG(@"[STATUS] Starting synchronous request %@",self);
#endif
    [self setSynchronous:YES];
    [self setRunLoopMode:ASIHTTPRequestRunLoopMode];
    [self setInProgress:YES];

    if (![self isCancelled] && ![self complete]) {
        [self main];
        while (!complete) {
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:[self runLoopMode] beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
        }
    }

    [self setInProgress:NO];
}
```

In while loop app crashes.
Am I doing something wrong...?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please be aware that `ASIHttpRequest` is deprecated and no longer supported, the developer suggest you move to another network library. `ASIHttpRequest` has known bug in iOS 7 and 8. I would suggest you move to `AFNetworking`

Comment: Hi rckoenes, 
Thanks for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know, the answer has been put there in the Questions' comment, but following is my explanation!

I was wondering why these people still use AsiHTTP for their projects.
It's been deprecated and also abandoned by its developer before or around iOS 5 and iOS 6!!! I've also used AsiHTTP library too, but that's only when I was learning to develop iOS apps and that's only for studying purpose only!

Better start using something like **AFNetworking**, a very easy to use networking library, which supports both iOS and Mac OS X both!

See the following links,

1. http://afnetworking.com/
2. https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking
3. http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial