# ASIFormDataRequest post method is not working in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi i am beginner in Ios and in my project there is facility for users "ForGotPassword" request

For this i have written some code but that is not working

i.e is objectFromJSONString response shows like -->Message: "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI "my url."

what did i do here wrong ,is it my problem or server side problem? please help me

### my code:-

```
  - (IBAction)submitBtnClicked:(id)sender {


        NSLog(@"password ---->>> %@",self.MedicalIdTxt.text);

        NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"my url"];

        NSLog(@"urlStr --->>> %@",urlStr);

        ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];

        [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

        [request setPostValue:self.MedicalIdTxt.text forKey:@"MedicaidId"];

        [request setDelegate:self];

        [request startAsynchronous];

        [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

    }

    - (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {

        NSLog(@"requestFinished");

        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

        NSLog(@"%@",request);
        NSString *receivedString = [request responseString];

        NSLog(@"receivedString %@",receivedString);

        NSDictionary * jsonObj=[[NSDictionary alloc]init];

        jsonObj = [receivedString objectFromJSONString];

        NSLog(@"jsonObj result is%@",jsonObj);

        NSString *messageStr = [jsonObj objectForKey:@"message"];

        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:messageStr delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];


    }

    - (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {

        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

        NSString *receivedString = [request responseString];

         UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:receivedString message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
          [alertView show];

    }
```

here "jsonObj" not showing response which is coming from services what did i do here wrong?

Comment: which Xcode Version are you using?

Comment: i am using Version 6.4

Comment: if you are using same cod  then its fault in         NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"my url"];
 You should use your domain url rathe then @"my url".

Comment: i am not understand please explain clearly

Comment: Be ware that `ASIHTTPRequest ` is no longer being developed and has now bug in iOS 6 and higher. I would suggest you move to an other library like `AFNetworking`

Comment: @rckoenes  Yes you are right. I agreed.

Comment: its better to use https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: @m.v.n.kalyani  in  NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"my url"];  you are changing url when you are  using this code ?

Comment: is there no way to change my code using "ASIHTTPRequest"

Comment: NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://something"] i used like this

Comment: you should check that out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094471/asihttprequest-crashes-the-app-on-ios8

Comment: so which headers i have to import for this like  #import "AFHTTPClient.h"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91484/discussion-between-m-v-n-kalyani-and-piyush-patel).

Answer (score 0):

`ASIHTTPRequest` is not under maintenance since so long, so use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) instead:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager POST:@"your url"
       parameters:@{@"color": @"green"}
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```